# Disabling USB storage devices on OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: macos, usb-storage

How can I disable USB Ports (storage devices only) on OS X El Capitan (10.11), without using profile manager?

I already tried to use the `kextunload` command (`sudo kextunload IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext`), I also tried to disable SIP and then remove the .kext file but without any success.

We’ve got a large number of iMacs setup, where we don’t want the user to be able to control/use the USB ports.